# The best datatype to work with network buffers

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on the network application which is based on the `QT` framework. It's `QTcpSocket` uses `char` arrays for transfering and receiving data. Should I stick to the `char` in my class, which dealing with that data, or I can use `int8_t` (or even `uint8_t`) which I like better (because of guaranteed size and debugging convenience)?

Comment: Why not QByteArray?

Comment: I work with that data in the library which is not supposed to use QT classes

Comment: Just use what you like most/improves the readability of your code/try to follow the practices already used in the library. When casting, try to add relevant `static_assert`s to ensure your assumptions are true (f.ex `sizeof(uint8_t) == sizeof(char)`) on the target platform.